# How to transform JavaScript filter function to Django Python?

Tags: python, django

I have the following filter function on JavaScript and I need to do the same on Django.

This is my JavaScript function:

```
absentAttendees() {     
      return this.meeting.attendees.filter((element) => this.timeAttendees(element.user.id) <= 0 || (element.absent && this.timeAttendees(element.user.id) <= 0));
    }

timeAttendees(user) {
      let timeUser = 0
      this.meeting.meeting_times.forEach((time) => {
        if (time.user.id === user) {
          timeUser = timeUser + time.time
        }
      })

      return timeUser
    }
```

Here is what I have so far on Django, but it tells me that the object I'm passing doesn't have the attribute 'user'

```
timeList = filter(timeAttendees, meeting.attendees.all())
def timeAttendees(item):
            timeUser = 0
            
            for time in time_list:
                if(time.user.id == item.user.id):
                    timeUser = timeUser + time.time
                
            return timeUser
```

meeting.attendees refers to the following model:

```
meeting = models.ForeignKey(
Meeting, related_name="attendees", on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, related_name="attendee", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
)
idd = models.CharField(max_length=255)
organizer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
absent = models.BooleanField(default=True)
verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: you forgot to save the value of `meeting.attendees.all().filter(timeAttendees > 0)` in `time_list` i think . if not what is `time_list`

Comment: Right forgot about that part, although my main problem is that item on the function is not carrying the properties from the model

Comment: What is `item` ? an user or a structure of user or another model instance?

Comment: item would be the attendees model, which has properties and a user model inside

Comment: Can you edit and include the definition of every variable that is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `meeting` is some Meeting object, and item is valid object here is how you can replicate `timeAttendees` function:

```
meeting = <Meeting_object>
def get_time_attendees(item):
    global meeting
    return sum([interval.time for interval in meeting.meeting_times
                if interval.user.id == item.user.id])
```

Above function returns total time that user appeared in `meeting_times`. To get absent attendees, [**`filter()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [**`map()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) could do the job:

```
def get_absent_attendees(meeting):
    attendees = meeting.attendees.all()
    return list(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, list(map(get_time_attendees, attendees))))
```

`list(map(get_time_attendees, attendees))` calls `get_time_attendees` function in every attendees object and converts the result into a list. Then with `filter`, you grab the ones with attendance time less than zero.

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I needed.